# Is it realistic for soundwaves under water to "sink" or "float"?

Tags: acoustics, numerical-method

I'm studying soundwaves under water and I had a numerical problem that I was asking about.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904017/are-my-matlab-iterations-working

Now I wonder if you can tell me if it is realistic or some miscalculation that makes my sound waves appear like they are sinking and then floating up?

[image]

The horizontal axis is horizontal direction and the vertical axis is depth. I have the equations to make the model (these were previously calculated).

$c(z)=4800-20.2090+(17.3368)\frac{z}{1000}+(272.9057)exp(-\frac{-0.7528z}{1000})$
and

$c'(z)=(-0.7528*272.9067/1000)exp(-\frac{-0.7528z}{1000})  +17.3368/1000$

Now it says in the [assigment](http://www.csc.kth.se/utbildning/kth/kurser/DN1232/berva13/Lab3BuppgJO.pdf#page=16) "You should ﬁnd that the depth at xf = 25 nautical miles is close to 2500 feet."which is an answer I also get. But I don't fully understand the grphs. Then to find if another ray also reaches 2500 feet I have made an iteration to inspect the ranges of degrees and find that there can be other rays coming from different angles. Does that seem correct?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, then the answer is no. Sound waves are not matter, and thus do not sink or float, but instead, expand in a medium.